# Google Sheet API Implementation in Asp.net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Opening a Excel Spreadsheet in Asp.net Web Page through Google Spreadsheet API.

Actually I need to Create a spread sheet with per user login and based on some questions user will do some operation in Sheet and Finally Submit the sheet which will save on Google Sheet.

Then after i can read the sheets to evaluate the answer given by answer.

Looks really challenging...

Any Help Please??

I am concerned about showing the google sheet in web page.[something like this](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/published.do?rid=b0tmj0ff0d47373be46f5b21bef6756e8e3c2)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using .NET, get started with [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet). You can create spreadsheets by using [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create). To know more about sheet operations, check the [Sheets API guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

Comment: i looked on sheet api guide but not found any solution related to my scenario actually i want to display data in spreadsheet from data stored in sql server and then saved that excel back to sql server because i am creating a online excel test like application where i will populate an excel to webpage from data stored in sqlserver and user will perform some operations in excel like adding some formula and calculating some cell values and then after test i want to save that excel back to sql server.